# Error in autoscaling in ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I am using the autoscaling feature.
I set up the entire thing but the instance were automatically launched and terminated even if the instance does not reach the threshold.

I followed the steps:

1. Created an instance
2. Created a load balancer and registered an instance
3. Created a launch configuration
4. Created a cloud watch that cpu >=50 %\
5. An autoscale policy that launches and terminates the instance when CPU >=50 %

But as soon as I apply the policy the instances begin to launch and terminated without any CPU load and it continues

```
Cause: At 2014-01-14T10:51:08Z an instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the capacity from 0 to 1. 
StartTime: 2014-01-14T10:51:08.791Z
Cause: At 2014-01-14T10:02:16Z an instance was taken out of service in response to a system health-check.
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: So you had one registered instance running, then you applied the strategy and that instance was taken down or new instance was launched and then taken down? What is your desired capacity?

Comment: No this instance was always there when I registered. But new instances were automatically created and terminated. Desired capacity is between 1 to 2 instance.

Comment: what is desired capacity ?

Comment: You should check ping path and ping port on ELB, whether you get response. It seems that ELB brings the instances down as failed healthcheck and Autoscaling is reviving them in a vicious cycle.

Comment: How to do that ? how to check the ping path n port ?

Comment: One more thing to check is whether your Autoscaling group is attached to Elastic Load Balancer. I don't see it in your list. See the guide here [Use Elastic Load Balancing to Load Balance Your Auto Scaling Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SetUpASLBApp.html)

Comment: Can you ping your instance on port 80?

Comment: I have deleted the group because the instances were created and deleted automatically in every sec

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45338/discussion-between-user3086014-and-kukido)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Documentation:**
Follow the instructions on how to [Set Up an Auto-Scaled and Load-Balanced Application](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-register-lbs-with-asg.html)

**Notes:**
The instance, created outside of AutoScaling Group can be added to Elastic Load Balancer, but will not be monitored or managed by AutoScaling group.

Instance, created outside of AutoScaling Group can be marked as unhealthy by Elastic Load Balancer if the health check fails, but it will not cause AutoScaling Group to spawn a new instance.

Comment: I am always getting this error  sir `Instance has failed at least the Unhealthy Threshold number of health checks consecutively`

Comment: Now the launched configuration is defined correctly. The port 80 is open on the newly launched istance.. Please help me in this..

Comment: What is CPU load on those instances?

Comment: `Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st` Now this instance is IN service , earliaer it was out of service. Why so ?

Comment: But I am also getting notification of High CPu and Low CPU? Why so ? Even if the load is not >=50 % or <=50%

Comment: Both the instances are now in service? And the load will be tested on both the servers combinedly or individually ?

Comment: Please answer my query  sir

Comment: Individually. Honestly, it is hard to tell what is going on with your set-up. AS and ELB are pretty reliable products. I guess there's some misconfiguration. Did you try to get in touch with Amazon Support?

Comment: Yeah I have no of times posted there but I didn't get any reply from them

Comment: You should open support ticket if you believe you set up everything correctly.

Comment: Okay is that a paid service ?

Comment: Before getting in touch with AWS support, I suggest to follow the guide in the answer word for word, with default values or values specified in the guide. If that does not work, then get in touch with AWS support. If it does work indeed, then adjust it to your application. One thing though - is your Elastic Load Balancer in VPC or out?